# Reading PC turn-on and shut-down times?

Tags: python, windows

im writing a little routine to track my sleep cycle. Usually when i wake up I turn on my PC within minutes so reading out when the system turns on and when it shuts down would be great. This program here does the same function https://www.neuber.com/free/pctime/

I tried googling for a lib or function that can call these system events but most of the results are for turning on and shutting down the PC with command, so my question is:

What would be the best way to get the time the pc turns on and off?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to figure out the exact events to look for in the Windows event log. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219213/read-specific-windows-event-log-event

Comment: Unrelated to your coding problem: why not keep a pen and paper on your bedside table? ;-) Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks. Well i could use that program and just write everything into excel files. But it would be quite cool to have a little program running that just tells you if you a sleep deficit or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux (I'll assume Systemd here), you could write a service that executes code on startup/shutdown. That code would write the current timestamp to a CSV file, along with an indicator "startup" or "shutdown".

Here's a Python3 script that takes as first argument the type of timestamp to log to "updownlog.txt":

```
import os
import sys                         
import time                


def main():              
    logfile = "updownlog.csv"
    write_header = False

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Error: script takes exactly one argument")                    

    if sys.argv[1] != "shutdown" and sys.argv[1] != "startup":
        sys.exit("Error: First argument should be 'startup' or 'shutdown'")

    typ = sys.argv[1]

    if not os.path.exists(logfile):
        write_header = True

    with open("updownlog.csv", "a") as f:
        now = time.time()

        if write_header:
            f.write("type,timestamp\n")

        f.write("{},{}\n".format(typ, now))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Next, you'll need to create the system-service triggering this script. I'm shamelessly copying a solution offered in [this answer on UnixSX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294539): all credit to "John 9631"! If you still use an init.d based system there are great answers in that thread, too.

So, create the service file for your logging:

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/log_start_stop.service
```

and copy in the file content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Log startup and shutdown times

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart="/home/Sungod3k/log.py startup"
ExecStop="/home/Sungod3k/log.py shutdown"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable the service with the command:

```
systemctl enable log_start_stop
```

Granted, this won't yet tell you whether yo have a sleep deficit yet, so you'll need to do some post-processing, e.g. with Python or R, or even `awk`.

Comment: Im on Win, but the idea of executing a file on startup that just timestamps itself should be a good solution for starters.