# How to extract the data inside the print queue to txt file or any other format

Tags: python, windows, printing, data-extraction

most of the time I manually save the data (like date printed, copies count, file name... etc.) needed to calculate cost or save the information.
but the data is already there in the printer queue.

**so basically, I want to save data from the printing queue like the date, name of file, copies printed and other useful data in a separate file. maybe in a text file or something.**

so, I can just copy it in my app that I save these data on automatically once I print a document.

my System details: windows 11, my printer is: HP Page Wide Pro MFP 477DW and I only know python, I don't know any other language for now as am in high school
*Thank you in advance, and sorry if that is the wrong channel for this, I couldn't figure which is a better fit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to save the data from the printing queue like the date, name of file, copies printed in a separate file. maybe in a text file or something.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow, you should take a look to the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [minimum complete, and verifiable example page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get help from the community.

Comment: First you will need to do some setup so that this is even possible, see https://www.howtogeek.com/445760/how-to-check-your-printed-document-history-in-windows-10/ for instructions to tell windows how to keep print events long term.

You will then need to learn how to read the windows event log from python, an example of that would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219213/read-specific-windows-event-log-event.

Comment: thank you @jmoreno this answer looks really helpful, especially that i can understand python, but the Advanced tab in the printer queue is grayed out, and i cant modify it

Comment: That’s probably a permissions issue, don’t know for sure.

Comment: i now know how to deal with log files, but am not sure where to even find the specific information am seeking, the copies, how many pages, file name, date, status.
@jmoreno

Comment: The information you are looking for may not be present, but whatever is present will be in the free form text in the event.  If you have started capturing the information, you can use the event viewer to go look for what your printer does and how it formats the data.

Comment: Note, that once you have the information that is present, parsing it will, unlike most of this question, be on topic