# Read out when a program was last used win 10

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to write a program which checks when a program was lasted used.
I've tried different methods like checking the last modified date of the .exe as well as the registry, but non of these really work.
Do you guys have anther idea which I could try to get the date?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: where is your codes?

Comment: you could read windows event log and analyse the timestamps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219213/read-specific-windows-event-log-event

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).